# How to provision skype for business account to OIM user?

Tags: skype-for-business, oim, o365rwsclient, identitymanager

The integration between OIM and Microsoft Exchange is in place. Now we want to provision lync or skype for business to this user. What are the possible ways to do it? Also is it necessary to have O365 email id for every user whom we want to grant skype for business access?

My research says :

1. Create custom O365 connector and use Graph APIs to perform user life cycle operations like provisioning deprovisioning.
2. Use Exchange connector and create a process task that will call some API to create skype account.

Comment: I agree with your research that will be the best solution for mentioned usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach we choose to solve this problem is we created **Skype Enabled** user group in AD , and assigning the users to this AD group if they have skype enabled flag true in the user profile.

At Active directory end Admin guys are managing the provisioning of **Skype for Business Account**.